How to remove the specific key value pair from data set
Hello I am having below data set as, this data is being created by user input from the HTML.
{
  "Account": [
    {
      "Id": "001Aq00000YmKBQIA3",
      "Previously_Married__pc": false,
      "Previous_Marital_Status__pc": "Married"
    }
  ]
}

I am trying to delete the Previous_Marital_Status__pc  from above data set but getting 'Something went wrong error '  kindly help me.
Tried below approach
this.testArray.Account.forEach(account =>{
    if("Previous_Marital_Status__pc" in account){
          delete account.Previous_Marital_Status__pc;
    }
});


How did you get that array? Via a wire adapter? Please edit your question adding the relevant code

This question is similar to: Why delete operator doesn't work in LWC?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I have found this link on the stack exchange, explaining exactly what you're trying to do.
Check out this link for reference:
Why delete operator doesn't work in LWC?
You can try to set "Previous_Marital_Status__pc" as undefined

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
